# Cleaning up old shopping carts

Tags: asp.net, webforms, e-commerce, shopping-cart

The project I'm currently working on is an asp.net 2.0 e-commerce site. The shopping cart is session based so it expires after 30 minutes or so. I've converted it so that the carts are stored on the database but I'm left with the problem of cleaning up old carts. What is the best way to clean up the cart table in the database? I was going to make a page in the admin section that the owner can click so as to clean up shopping carts older than one week. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Just clear the session  when they click pay?

Comment: The cart is cleared when they click pay. The problem is the carts that people abandon. I'd like to have stuff still be in someone's cart if they come back a week later but maybe not more than that.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server? If you are using a version more than express then you should have the option to use SQL Server Agent a schedule a Stored Procedure that deletes all rows where the last updated date is over a week.

Comment: I am using sql server so I'll check into that.

Answer (score 1):

If people abandon their cart, they're simply no longer interested.

Simple solution to this would be to give the user the option to "Save Cart" (to DB). Presuming you have a working membership system with profiles set up they can easily view their cart on next login.

As Makit said, if you're running SQL Server above Express you can use a scheduled stored procedure. You have other options to do a clear-up of old entries such as a Windows Scheduled task or run the stored procedure from the start method in your Global.asax file.

This is the best suggestion I've come across: this data should not be deleted by you at all. Like Amazon a person may return months later and purchase something from the cart:

http://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/

Conclusion? Let the users opt to save cart contents themselves. Much better business model.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you can't store old carts indefinitely, given limited resources.

Therefore, here is a suggestion with two options.

**1.** Create a Stored Procedure to remove old carts - get the business owner to determine how long old carts last, otherwise 1 month might be reasonable.

**2.** 
**option a)**
Use [SQL Server Agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189237.aspx) to run the Stored Procedure above each day or week:

> SQL Server Agent is a Microsoft Windows service that executes
>   scheduled administrative tasks, which are called jobs in SQL Server.

**option b)** 
If you are using SQL Express you won't have SQL Server Agent, so create a .sql file that executes the Stored Procedure above and a [batch file](http://www.wikihow.com/Write-a-Batch-File) that uses [SqlCmd](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) to run the SQL.

> A batch file contains a series of commands, and is commonly
>   written to automate frequently performed tasks.

Then create a Windows [Scheduled Task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7) to run the batch file daily or weekly.